# Slow threading with XNA 3.1

Tags: c#, multithreading, performance, xna

I have a pretty strange problem with threading in XNA. I'm working on a PC with Q9400.

The code below is launched in the `Update()` function of XNA.

```
        Stopwatch sw = new Stopwatch();

        Thread[] threads = new Thread[2];
        threads[0] = new Thread(() => Thread_UpdateDoodadsMovable(gameTime));
        threads[1] = new Thread(() => Thread_UpdateDoodadsRotated(gameTime));
        sw.Start();
        foreach (Thread t in threads)
        {
            t.Start();
        }
        foreach (Thread t in threads)
        {
            t.Join();
        }

        sw.Stop();
        Console.WriteLine("A " + sw.ElapsedTicks);
        sw.Reset();
```

Both threads are now 'empty' as the code is commented:

```
    public void Thread_UpdateDoodadsRotated(GameTime gametime)
    {
        // level.UpdateDoodadsRotated(gameTime);
    }
    public void Thread_UpdateDoodadsMovable(GameTime gametime)
    {
       // level.UpdateDoodadsMovable(gametime);
    }
```

The `sw.ElapsedTicks` returns between 7000 up to 10000. Can someone explain to me why is this happening?

I know that creating threads rather than taking them from `ThreadPool` is not the best way perfomance-wise but the thread creation takes a lot less time than `ElapsedTicks` return.

Comment: Can you change `ElapsedTicks` to `ElapsedMiliseconds`? The duration of a tick can vary and might be down to 100 nanoseconds. Then your durations would be 0.7 to 1 miliseconds, which seems reasonable.

Comment: I did change them and the durations are on level of 2 up to 3 miliseconds. I did a small console app with the same code and the times were similar. Is there some way to speed up threading? After all 1 second=1000 miliseconds, 1000/60=16.6 miliseconds for a frame and another 2 or 3 taken up by threading make a diffrence.

Comment: It would be interesting to see the times at one more place in the code: after the starts and before the joins (between the for loops).  This way we could see if the time is spent in setup or teardown. Additionally, I dont think its correct to say "Is there some way to speed up threading?" when the thread code is commented out and you're just measuring setup and teardown times.

Comment: The 16.6 miliseconds you calculated is not the duration of the update method for one frame. If `Update()` is finished, then it is finished. It will be called again, to achieve a frequency of 60 Hz or whatever. 3 miliseconds should be no problem. If this is too slow for you, you already mentioned the answer: Use the thread pool or decrease update frequency.